# how to set python numpy array size limit

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, size

I'm trying to calculate the average size of a contour/ball. I've used arclength to calculate the perimeter of the ball, then found out the diameter. My problem is that the contour values is constantly changing.

I want to input the first 10 values of the diameter into a np.array and calculate the mean to use as my object size. I'm new to python, been trying multiple methods but haven't found a solution to either set the size or extract the first 10 array tuples. I've tried pulling u the first 10 using for i in range.

My current code is:

```
def average_diam (diameter):
    av_diameter = np.array(diameter)
    for i in np.arange(1, len(av_diameter)):
            for i in av_diameter >= 10:
                    average = np.mean()
                    print(average)


perimeter = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
diameter = perimeter / pi
average = average_diam(diameter)
```

thanks for the help!!

Comment: Diameter in this situation is a single `float` so thus your `numpy` array has length 1. Assuming it is an array you can do something like `for i in range(0, 10: av_diameter = diameter[i]` then just print `np.mean(av_diameter)`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming diameter is an list of elements you simply can do something like

```
def average_diam(x):
    av_diameter = np.zeros(10)
    for i in range(0, 10):
         av_diameter[i] = x[i]
    return np.mean(av_diameter)

average_diam(diameter)
```

You honestly can just do a one liner for this without calling a function:

`average = np.mean(np.asarray(diameter[0:10]))`

Comment: I get an: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__' error on both methods?

Comment: Then `diameter` is not a list.  It's a number.  Make sure you know what objects/variables are before you start throwing them around.

Comment: Oh I see! When I printed the diameter out the values constantly changed. So I thought by putting these in an array it'd store all the different sizes

Comment: Yeah I mentioned on the comments that the diameter is a float. This would work assuming it is a list as you mention in your problem ("First 10 diameter values")